# Modifying nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Given this two dicts:

```
empty = {'151': {'1': 'empty', '0': 'empty', '2': '2.30'}}
full = {'151': {'1': 3.4, '0': 3.6, '2': 2}}
```

Firstly, I want to check if `empty.keys() == full.keys()` if it holds, I want to replace the `empty` values with corresponding value from `full` dictionary. It ought to result in:

```
not_empty = {'151': {'1': '3.4', '0': '3.6', '2': '2.30'}}
```

My solution so far: I thought I would identify all the keys with `empty` values using regex, but for whatever reason my code so far, produces an empty dict `{}`.

```
import re 
find_empty = re.findall("'(\d)':\s'empty'", str(empty))[0]

if empty.keys() == full.keys():
    k = empty.values()[0].keys()
    v = empty.values()[0].values()
    print {k:v for k,v in empty.values()[0].iteritems()\
                   if empty.values()[0][find_empty] != 'empty'}
```

I hoped it can output `{'151': {'2': '2.30'}}` for a good starting point. Anyway, I guess there exists more clean solution then regex for this task so any hints are welcomed!

Comment: Is `151` always the key? Is there going to be more than one key?

Comment: There will be a lot of keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex is not the right tool for this job.  I would suggest a recursive approach like the following.

```
empty = {'151': {'1': 'empty', '0': 'empty', '2': '2.30'}}
full = {'151': {'1': 3.4, '0': 3.6, '2': 2}}

def repl(a, b):
    clean = {}
    for k, v in a.items():
        # This is the case where we want to replace what we have in b if we have something.  Just in case, use the dict.get method and provide a default.
        if v == 'empty': 
            clean[k] = b.get(k, 'Not there')
        # If the value is another dict, then call this function with the value, and put the return as the value for our current key
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            v_clean = repl(v, b.get(k, {}))
            clean[k] = v_clean
        # The value isn't equal to 'empty', and it isn't another dict, so just keep the current value.
        else:
            clean[k] = v
    # Finally, return the cleaned up dictionary.
    return clean

print repl(empty, full)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'151': {'1': 3.4, '0': 3.6, '2': '2.30'}}
```

**EDIT**  I am not sure if this takes care of all of your cases, but it probably worth a look anyway.

```
empty = {'151': {'1': 'empty', '0': 'empty', '2': '2.30', '8': ['empty', 'empty', 5, {"foo2": "bar2", "1": "empty"}]}}
full = {'151': {'1': 3.4, '0': 3.6, '2': 2, '8': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', {"foo3": "bar3", "1": "2"}]}}

def repl(a, b):
    if isinstance(a, dict) and isinstance(b, dict):
        clean = {}
        for k, v in a.items():
            # This is the case where we want to replace what we have in b if we have something.  Just in case, use the dict.get method and provide a default.
            if v == 'empty':
                clean[k] = b.get(k, 'Not there')
            # If the value is another dict, then call this function with the value, and put the return as the value for our current key
            elif isinstance(v, dict):
                v_clean = repl(v, b.get(k, {}))
                clean[k] = v_clean
            # The value isn't equal to 'empty', and it isn't another dict, so just keep the current value.
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                v_clean = repl(v, b.get(k, []))
                clean[k] = v_clean
            else:
                clean[k] = v
        # Finally, return the cleaned up dictionary.
    elif isinstance(a, list) and isinstance(b, list):
        clean = []
        for item_a, item_b in zip(a, b):
            if item_a == 'empty':
                clean.append(item_b)
            elif isinstance(item_a, dict):
                clean_a = repl(item_a, item_b)
                clean.append(clean_a)
            else:
                clean.append(item_a)
    return clean

print repl(empty, full)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'151': {'1': 3.4, '0': 3.6, '2': '2.30', '8': ['foo', 'bar', 5, {'1': '2', 'foo2': 'bar2'}]}}
```

Comment: if you have some time, could you please update your answer by adding a solution as if `empty` and `full` were dictionaries with lists as values? eg. `empty = {'151': ['empty', 'empty', '2.30']}` The logic of replacing would be the same. I do not really understand the solution you gave me, and I happen to need it to handle lists as well.

Comment: @nutship: Updated with another example to handle lists.

Comment: A huge, huge thank you for caring to update on request! I wish I could reward you with  more points.

Comment: More important than points to me is that you take the time to walk through what is happening so you understand how to apply these concepts for solving problems you have in the future.  For nested structures, recursion is often your friend.